# Access service running in a container from browser

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using docker to run a test environment locally On Ubuntu 16.04. I spin up a container using the command -

`fwx@asus:~$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -v ~/work/website/:/website -it test-env bash`

This puts me inside the container where I do some initial setup and start the service like so -

`root@c98d858cb1a4:/website# start-service`

The service is configured to the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and `docker inspect` on the container provides me the IP address `172.17.0.2`.
As I understand from the multiple blog / forum posts addressing similar issues, I should be able to access the pages served through a browser on my host at `http://172.17.0.2:3000`. However, trying to access it thusly throws a connection error that the website cannot be reached.

I have tried various solutions proposed on similar questions including adding `172.17.0.0` to the route, but to no avail. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you do curl within the container? and check with telnet from host to container > telnet  172.17.0.2 3000

Comment: What is the IP Address of your Ubuntu machine (Host-machine)?  Try using that host-machine-IP-Address:3000.

Comment: @JinnaBalu Curl within the container to any website works. telnet doesn't work.

Comment: @fly2matrix tried with my private and public ip addresses. did not work.

Comment: is app / service up within the container. check with the curl being in the same container.

Comment: Yep it is up within the container. Checked with curl.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a docker container it will be assigned a private ip, To access the container you need to expose it which in your case is `-p 3000:3000` try accessing the service from your host ip address and also try by disabling firewall.

Comment: I tried using my host's private and public IP:3000. It did not work.

Comment: Is your host on public cloud ?

Comment: No. It's my personal laptop connected to the internet through a well-known ISP.

Comment: Did you disabled the firewall and can you confirm with telnet ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I have disabled the firewall, but I didn't understand what you want me to confirm with telnet?

Comment: You can telnet to your machine to the particular port and verify it’s accessible or not

Comment: Hmm. I could not telnet to my public IP address. But I don't have a firewall active. What should I do?

Comment: I enabled a firewall and added a rule with ufw: `sudo ufw allow 3000`. However, I still cannot access the service at my public IP address.

Comment: Can you login to container and verify the process is running at 3000

Comment: yes i've verified that multiple times. ran a curl from within the container again.